# FormData append not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I wrote this to upload an image to my local Apache webserver using `input` element in HTML. The `file` is logged as not empty, but why is the `form_data` completely empty?

```
$('#upload-image').change(function(e){
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var imageType = /image.*/;
    if (!file.type.match(imageType))
        return;
    console.log(file);
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file', file);
    console.log(form_data);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/upload.php',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

});
```

This is my `upload.php` on local webserver

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    }
    else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
        $target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/uploads/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];
        echo $target_path;
    }
?>
```

The `console.log(response)` logs all the code lines of PHP file, instead of the returned result of `echo`

Comment: have you tried using in the url just 'upload.php' ? Is not common to see an absolute path, and not to mention the localhost, remember that the AJAX call depends where the javascript file sits, so for example if you have a folder within your root called "phpFiles/upload.php", then that should be put in the url.

Comment: console.log(form_data);   what is o/p your getting here?

Comment: What are you expecting to see? You can't really log a formData object, so it should be empty, even if the file is there. Did you check the server if the file was received or not.

Comment: @adeneo Where will it store? I can't find the location of `uploads` folder

Comment: @adeneo I think it is `/var/www/html` but I can't see `uploads` there

Comment: You're the one whos telling it where to move the files, so just create a folder and store the files there ?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

When logging a formData object with just `console.log(formData)` it always returns empty, as you can't log formData.

If you just have to log it before sending it, you can use `entries()` to get the entries in the formData object

```
$('#upload-image').change(function(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var imageType = /image.*/;

    if (!file.type.match(imageType)) return;

    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file', file);

    for (var key of form_data.entries()) {
        console.log(key[0] + ', ' + key[1]);
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/upload.php',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: When will it store on webserver? I can't find the location of `uploads`

Comment: I think it is `/var/www/html` but I can't see `uploads` there

Comment: exactly what i wanted..Thanks

Comment: Brilliant! Trying to implement `HTMLFormElement` instead of just regular forms, I had been trying `console.log(formData)` and editing my form and trying again (and repeat), trying to return something until I saw this. Thanks @adeneo

Comment: when i do this, it just shows ``{}`` in my files entry

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed myself that the `contentType: false` will only work on jQuery 1.7.0 and above. So make sure that you're using the right jQuery version.