# How to append file to forData object vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to append the file from the input to the `formData` object, But when I console log the object it's empty. I tried multiple solutions and I can't seem to figure out the problem.

File input

`<input class="btn btn-sm btn-rounded btn-noborder btn-primary" type="file" @change="uploadReturnLabel($event)" :disabled="!editState"/>`

Method

```
uploadReturnLabel(e) {
                if (!e.target.files.length) {
                    return;
                }
                var data = new FormData();
                data.append('return_label', e.target.files[0]);
                console.log(data);
                /*
                post('rma-return-label/'+this.rma.rma_ticket_id, data)
                    .then((res) => {
                        console.log(res)
                    })
                 */
            },
```

Comment: why not bind input value with `v-model`?

Comment: You can't set a value on a file input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer in this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40062588/5599288)

to log FormData, you can use entries()

```
for (var key of data.entries()) {
    console.log(key[0] + ', ' + key[1]);
}
```