# FormData cant take a file from a component state field in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a **React** component with a file type input:

```
class AttrUploadFile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      file: {},
      data: [],
      cols: [],
      fileload: false,
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    this.props.reportChange(file);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form action="">
          <label htmlFor="file">Seleccione el Archivo Excel</label>
          <br />
          <input
            type="file"
            className="form-control"
            id="file"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <br />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AttrUploadFile;
```

This components stores its value on a component state field:

```
catchChange(file) {
    this.setState({ file: file });
  }
```

And when the user chooses the action, a method sends the file to a **Django Rest Framework** endpoint, through a **redux** action:

```
handleAccept = () => {
    let file = this.state.file;

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("xlsx", file);
    formData.append("name",file.name);
    this.props.sendFiles(this.props.currentRepository, formData)
  }
```

The problem here is that `formData.append("xlsx", file)` adds nothing to `formData`. I know by debugging that `this.state.file` has this value:
[image]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you facing any error?

Comment: @ManirajMurugan No error at all, just that I'm unable to send the file because formData is always empty after `formData.append(file)`

Comment: ```formData()``` would always empty even you console.log .. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40062588/7785337 .. Could you create an working example like this https://codesandbox.io/s/kkpq42r413 for better understanding..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan you are right. I have checked and I can see that `formData` contains `[object File]`. It appears now that my problem lies on the `Content-Type` of the request, or something like that. Very good reference you sent.

Comment: Yes as I you have not mentioned the ```Content-Type``` in question, I thought you might have used the right one..