# JS Object width FormData convert zu in String

Tags: javascript

How do I get it to convert the individual data from the object back into a string. When I display the object with console.log, it only says "FormData { }". And when I search in it, I can't find my data.

---

```
formData = new FormData();
formData.append('name1', 'value1');
console.log(formData);
```

---

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40062588/19330634)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test = new FormData();
test.append('name1', 'value1');

for (var key of test.entries()) {
   console.log(key[0] + ', ' + key[1]);
}
```